# How to generate a prediction interval from a decision tree regression model?

Tags: python, pandas, decision-tree

I have used a decision tree regression model in Pandas for predictions. Is there a way through which I can generate a 95% prediction interval for the model (get the range where in 95% of cases, the real value is contained in it)?

Here is my code:

```
import math
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# One-hot encoding the data
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer

def Trend_method(colOfInterest, fileIn):
    DF= pd.read_excel(fileIn)
    # Preprocess the data
    GroupTrendData = DF
    GroupTrendData = GroupTrendData.dropna()                
    X = GroupTrendData.drop(columns = [colOfInterest])
    y = GroupTrendData[colOfInterest]
    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 41)
    
    # To deal with categorical data
    ohe = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = "ignore")
    column_transformer = make_column_transformer(
                (ohe, ['NAME', 'CNTRY_OF_RESIDENCE']),
                remainder='passthrough')
    X_train = column_transformer.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test = column_transformer.transform(X_test)
    model = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state = 41)
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    predictions = model.predict(X_test)
    # Display the real vs predicted values
    RealVsPredDF = pd.DataFrame({'Real Values' : Y_test, 'Predicted Values' : predictions.reshape(-1)})
    print(RealVsPredDF)

    # How do I find the prediction interval from here?
```

Could finding the 2.5 percentile and 97.5 percentile of the predicted data be taken as the prediction interval?